# mySQL query to count cases per user

Tags: mysql, count, inner-join

Hey all i have the following query:

```
SELECT UA.Org, UA.AccNum, UA.Category, COUNT(UC.CaseNum) AS totalCases
FROM userAccount UA
INNER JOIN userCase UC ON UA.AccNum = UC.Userlink 
ORDER BY UA.AccNum, UC.QNum ASC
LIMIT 1, 15;
```

And i am looking to get something like so out of it:

```
  org      | Account  | Category   | totalCases
  ---------------------------------------------
  blah 1   | 2883513  | Blah here 1| 2
  blah 2   | 2998619  | Blah here 2| 3
  blah 3   | 3063328  | Blah here 3| 1
 etc etc...
```

However, when i run that query above all i get is 0 records. Taking the **COUNT(UC.CaseNum) AS totalCases** produces my 15 rows like normal.

The user could have 0 cases or more when it does the query. I'm sure i need a **GROUPBY** in there but without data coming first, its best not to keep adding to my non-working query.

The data without the totalCases looks like this:

```
org      | Account  | Category   | Case
-------------------------------------------
blah 1   | 2883513  | Blah here 1| 5691245
blah 1   | 2883513  | Blah here 1| 8952214
blah 2   | 2998619  | Blah here 2| 1478523
blah 2   | 2998619  | Blah here 2| 9965821
blah 2   | 2998619  | Blah here 2| 1028745
blah 3   | 3063328  | Blah here 3| 3605487
etc etc...
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you get `0` rows is because you are using a aggregate function and then limiting your results to start from the `second row`

Your query should be like

```
SELECT UA.Org, UA.AccNum, UA.Category, COUNT(UC.CaseNum) AS totalCases
FROM userAccount UA
INNER JOIN userCase UC ON UA.AccNum = UC.Userlink 
GROUP BY UA.AccNum, UA.Org, UA.Category
ORDER BY UA.AccNum, UC.QNum ASC
```

You can then `limit` the results of the above query

Since you are using `INNER JOIN` here, the results wont contain a user having `0` test cases, you can change this behavior by using a `left join`

Comment: this is not true on *"...because you are using a aggregate function and then limiting your results to start from the second row"*. the `GROUP BY` clause is executed first before the `LIMIT` does.

Comment: but wouldn't the overall results of the query be just 1 row, i.e the 0th row?

Comment: I will take your answer since you had the added **Left join** part that i needed to add as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
SELECT UA.Org, UA.AccNum, UA.Category, COUNT(UC.CaseNum) AS totalCases
FROM userAccount UA
INNER JOIN userCase UC ON UA.AccNum = UC.Userlink 
GROUP BY UA.Org, UA.AccNum, UA.Category
ORDER BY UA.AccNum, UC.QNum ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the relationship between `userAccount` and `userCase` table is `one-to-many`. There might be many `userCase` records for one `userAccount`.

Try this one:

```
SELECT UA.Org, UA.AccNum, UA.Category, COUNT(UC.CaseNum) AS totalCases
FROM userAccount UA
INNER JOIN userCase UC ON UA.AccNum = UC.Userlink
GROUP BY UA.AccNum
ORDER BY UA.AccNum, UC.QNum ASC
LIMIT 1, 15;
```

Added GROUP BY `UA.AccNum`, if you have the `Id` column, better use that one.